# Xamarin Image Source Not Showing on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a cross platform app using a PCL where you can take a photo using the camera, the image is saved to a local db (to later be synced elsewhere). The app also loads the last image and displays it on screen in an  with the source bound to the view model.

This works perfectly on iOS but Android wont show the bound image.

I have tested that i can show an image on android by setting the Source to "icon.png" which works.

Xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>            
    <Image HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Green" Source="{Binding CameraImage}"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Take Picture" Command="{Binding GetPhoto}"/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel

```
public void LoadLatestImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var imageDBO = DatabaseHelpers.LocalDatabase.Table<ImageDBO>().OrderByDescending(i => i.DateCreated).FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
    if (imageDBO != null)
    {
        CameraImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return new MemoryStream(imageDBO.ImageData); });
    }
}
```

Binding

```
private ImageSource _cameraImage;
public ImageSource CameraImage
{
    get { return _cameraImage; }
    set
    {
        if (_cameraImage != value)
        {
            _cameraImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CameraImage));
        }
    }
}
```

Just a note: I have attempted to find a solution to this on Xamarin forums and stack overflow but similar issues on here aren't the same and their solutions don't seem to help. It seems most of these issues are caused by access to local resources however that shouldn't apply here as my source is straight from a bite array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's nice to see a new(ish) user showing code and asking a clear question. I've given you an upvote to help you. You could further improve your question by showing what you _did_ find on the Xamarin Forums and here on Stack Overflow. Then explain how it didn't help. ("I tried X as described [here], but ..." or "It says [here] I should use X, but that does not help in my case because ..."). Then [edit] that into your question. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I added a bit more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was happening due to the Byte array produced by the image from the Android camera being too large to bind to the view (an android issue only). Reducing the image size/quality fixed the issue.